# Find used drivers for printer

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, cups

My Canon printer PIXMA MP170 (via USB) doesn't work on Debian 7 AMD64 but does work on my Ubuntu 12.04 i386. I've tried a lot of tutorials about this but had no success. For now, I'd like to to know more about which driver is used for this printer on my Ubuntu 12.04.

I'm looking for a way to find which driver CUPS uses for my printer on Ubuntu and maybe use this information to make it work on Debian.

Comment: The kernel (`lspci` lists hardware detected by the kernel) only controls the port (e.g. USB) that the printer is connected to.  The printer itself is managed by CUPS, and so you would have to determine which CUPS driver is being used.

Comment: Ok, i understand. Do you know how know what driver CUPS use ? (I will edit the question for more pertinence)

Comment: See also this question: ["Which driver (and PPD version) is my printer using?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/276437/which-driver-and-ppd-version-is-my-printer-using)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the command [`lsusb`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lsusb.8.html) if it's a USB-based printer. You can get more information about it using additional `-v` switches to `lsusb`.